# Windows Server 2016 - enable SMTP logs

Tags: logging, smtp, windows-server-2016

Does anyone know how to enable and view the SMTP logs on Windows Server 2016?  I could not find any information on Google.  I am getting this message from a client `Email: Login denied on host smtp://10.1.1.11:25.` and want to figure out why I am getting this.

Comment: Are you talking about logs for the SMTP service which is part of IIS and log settings are configured in IIS Manager and default to the IIS log location. Or, are you running exchange or some other mail service?

Comment: @Appleoddity I am talking about the former.

Comment: It appears I found them in `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`.  I followed the directions on this [website](https://theitbros.com/configure-iis-log-location-on-windows-server-2016/) titled "How to configure, view and change IIS Log location on Windows Server 2016"